# How to replace strings in file without regex?

Tags: command-line, 10.04, bash, sed, regex

I need to replace some strings in files (from command line) but I don't want to use `sed -i` because my string contains lots of funny characters which need to be correctly escaped. Is there a way to turn off regex and just replace plain string?

Answer (score 11):

You may have better luck using perl - which supports literal string matching via the `\Q` (quoted sentence) modifier e.g.

```
perl -pe 's/\Qstring/replacement/g'
```

See for example this article [Perl Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) at boost.org