# sed to var which save special characters

Tags: sed, special-characters

Hello I m tring to use

```
sed -i -e s/"$before"/"$after"/g ~/.A/$sfi
```

to substitube an line on a file .A
from $before to $after but bouth variables contain characters & and I think is it the cause of not working someone can give an solution for this please?
Thanks Very Much

Comment: You may find `perl` to be a better choice: see [How to replace strings in file without regex?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395602/how-to-replace-strings-in-file-without-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the ampersand in the replacement part that is like causing your concern. An Ampersand in the replacement part is replaced with the text that matched the pattern. An example:

```
$ before="time&again"
$ after="to&fro"
$ sed "s/$before/$after/" <<END
> hello
> world time&again !
> END
hello
world totime&againfro !
```

So, the matched text `time&again` is replaced by `to&fro`, except the `&` between "to" and "fro" is itself replaced by the matched text.

The solution is to escape the ampersand in the replacement side. Using [bash parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) will give the desired results:

```
sed "s/$before/${after//&/\\&}/"
```

Comment: "I think is it the cause of not working" ... OP pretty much knows that's the problem. The question is: what's the solution?

Comment: I suspect he didn't know why it was a problem. But of course you're right. Answer updated